Find Element ID or Name through Inspect action in Chrome
I need to find the element ID or name of the input text in a website and then click a button to return some values. However I do not see the element ID or Name in the code after I click inspect tab in website (as shown in attachment). I can see see other parameters like class and levels of the input text like Start date and end date.
Class name for both start/end date text is seen to be same, so could not use findelementbyclass to find the text element name. Can anyone suggest alternative ways to find element id or name when its not mentioned or hidden from website inspect part in chrome?
enter image description here

The element does not have an ID if it does not show up.
Also not sure if this is more a question on Chrome instead of coding. If this is related to your code then please provide more details and code samples

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Do you necessarily want an ID or name? Would a CSS or XPath selector work?
You can get these as follows:

Open Developer Tools with right-click and then Inspect.
In the Inspector tab the relevant portion of the document should be selected (if not, then find it).
Now right-click again and choose Copy followed by either CSS Selector or XPath.

Either of those should enable you to select the relevant element in your code.
A potential problem is that these selectors can be fragile and are likely to break if there are structural changes to the document. It would be better to craft a selector specifically for the <input> element you're looking for. To this end, please provide the URL of the page you are wanting to scrape.
Looking at the HTML extract in your screenshot you might be able to get away with something as simple as this:
input[min="2019-05-18"]

since the min attribute is not present in the other visible <input> element. However, that will depend on whether there are other elements on the tag with the min attribute set or not.
As suggested, use a selector like the one above. For the URL you've provided this code will update the start and end dates separately.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import time

driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    options=webdriver.ChromeOptions(),
)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

URL = "https://www.nepsealpha.com/nepse-data"
driver.get(URL)

time.sleep(5)

date_start = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[min='2019-05-28']")

date_start.send_keys("01/01/2020")
date_start.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

date_end = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[max='2024-05-28']:not([min])")

date_end.send_keys("01/01/2021")
date_end.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

time.sleep(10)
            
driver.quit()


Thanks for your suggestions.There are 2 identical input texts start date and end date with all same parameters, even the input min or max value mentioned.Can I choose ist or second text using findelementby ? Or is there another option to choose a unique text by passing multiple values in findelementby ? Would apprecite your answer.

Please provide URL for the page you're trying to scrape so that I can give you the best CSS selector.

"https://www.nepsealpha.com/nepse-data" is the link website from which I want to extract stock data by providing start date, end date and stock symbol as input. I would prefer one time five years data for all the stocks in one excel sheet and then different excel sheet for extracting data each day for all stock indices available. It would be better if I could get the data extraction process automation code in vba  along with looping process through each symbol for start date/end date provided( one time all historical 5 years data and then for each day).@datawookie

I am using selenium and chrome driver and can easily extract data from any website like google.com where inputs element ids or name is available. Here is sample used:
"Set mybrowser = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
'mybrowser.Start baseUrl:="https://www.nepsealpha.com/nepse-data"
mybrowser.Start baseUrl:="https://www.google.com"
mybrowser.Get ("/")
mybrowser.FindElementById("APjFqb").SendKeys "madhu"
'mybrowser.FindElementByClass("form-group col-md-2").SendKeys "2019-05-28""

See my updated answer which includes code that modifies both of those date fields.

Thanks, I appreciate your help. It seems python script, can it be modified to vba script ? I would appreciate your answer

I think you should have specified that in the original question. You have everything you need to write the VBA script and ChatGPT will probably do it for you.

thanks but the chatgpt conversion of to excel vba of the code didnt work. Please help me get the solution.It says object not found

I would prefer one time five years data for all the stocks in one excel sheet and then different excel sheet for extracting data each day for all stock indices available. It would be better if I could get the data extraction process automation code in vba along with looping process through each symbol for start date/end date provided( one time all historical 5 years data and then for each day)

Sorry, I don't do VBA. The Python solution in my answer works. I'm afraid that you'll need to figure out how to translate to VBA.
